# Telerik controls and UI Automation?

Tags: testing, telerik, automated-tests, integration-testing, ui-automation

I'm currently doing some proof of concept for the test team to test our WPF app. Everything works great except for when we try to do Assertions on items in the Grid.

We are currently using Telerik GridView for WPF 4, which obviously isn't a standard WPF control. Have anyone used any UI Automation Test tools that work with third party controls?

Telerik do have a ui automation tool but it's only for webpages and Silverlight, not WPF.

Please help!

Thanks,
Ash.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the last release of Telerik Test Studio supports automation of WPF apps. You can read more [here](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/wpf-testing.aspx).